# Android: How can I put my notification on top of notification area?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notification-bar, notification-bar

I'm trying to put my notification on top of notification area.

A solution is to set the parameter "when" to my notification object with a future time like:

```
notification.when = System.currentTimeMills()*2;
```

The code that I'm using in this:

```
long timeNotification = System.currentTimeMillis()*2;
Notification notification = new Notification(statusIcon,c.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),timeNotification);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.when = timeNotification;
notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
```

but some apps (like Facebook) are able to put a simple notification with their current time over mine.

If I refresh my notification it remains under these ones.

What parameters I have to set to put my `Notification` to the top of the notifications area?

Comment: what Android OS version you are testing on?

Comment: Android 4.1.1 Jelly Bean

Answer (score 20):

You should do this. Other answers seem outdated.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_small_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("This is a test notification with MAX priority")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) is important. It can also be replaced with any of the following as per requirement.

**Different Priority Levels Info:**

**PRIORITY_MAX** --
Use for critical and urgent notifications that alert the user to a condition that is time-critical or needs to be resolved before they can continue with a particular task.

**PRIORITY_HIGH** --
Use primarily for important communication, such as message or chat events with content that is particularly interesting for the user. High-priority notifications trigger the heads-up notification display.

**PRIORITY_DEFAULT** --
Use for all notifications that don't fall into any of the other priorities described here.

**PRIORITY_LOW** --
Use for notifications that you want the user to be informed about, but that are less urgent. Low-priority notifications tend to show up at the bottom of the list, which makes them a good choice for things like public or undirected social updates: The user has asked to be notified about them, but these notifications should never take precedence over urgent or direct communication.

**PRIORITY_MIN** --
Use for contextual or background information such as weather information or contextual location information. Minimum-priority notifications do not appear in the status bar. The user discovers them on expanding the notification shade.

For more details check the following link: 
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#correctly_set_and_manage_notification_priority

Comment: I want to trigger heads-up notification but setting priority to PRIORITY_HIGH isn't working for me.

Comment: Apps can still take over the top position

Comment: priority max is deprecated.

Comment: PRIORITY_MAX is deprecated, use NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your notification `Ongoing`, when it will appear higher then other usual notification. But in this case user would **not** be able to clear it manually.

In order to do this set flags to your `Notification` object:

```
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edit my question to show you my code. I already use your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `priority` of the notification to high

documentation > [Notification Priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#priority)

Also check this question may it could help you [Pin Notification to top of notification area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189817/pin-notification-to-top-of-notification-area)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edit my question to show you my code. I already use your suggestions.

Comment: So what is the result you are getting ?

Comment: Some apps are able to put their notifications over mine.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that if you want a "heads-up" notification i.e., one that displays over the top of the current user window you must have the following set in your builder:

```
setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
```

The reference is in the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#//apple_ref/Constant/DEFAULT%255FVIBRATE):

> A notification that vibrates is more likely to be presented as a heads-up notification, on some platforms.

**Complete example for a heads-up notification:**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_small_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("This is a test notification with MAX priority")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
```