# How do I redisplay Ticker Text?

Tags: android, android-notifications

For my app, I use one notification ID as to not clutter the Notifications Menu of a user. Each of my notifications have Ticker Text. When there are no notifications from my app, and the user gets notified, the ticker text displays. When a notification already exists, and is merely updated, the ticker text does not get displayed.

I made a work around which is very hacky, where I cancel the notification before I notify, but this ultimately causes a very obvious lag with vibrations.

Currently how I have notifications happening:

```
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_logo)
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentText(extras.getString("summary"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(extras.getString("extended_text"))
            )
            .setLights(Color.WHITE, NOTIF_LIGHT_INTERVAL, NOTIF_LIGHT_INTERVAL)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("mainActivityNotification", true);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 424242, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    final Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.tickerText = extras.getString("title") + "\n" +
                              extras.getString("summary") + "\n" +
                              extras.getString("post_body");

    mNotificationManager.notify(GATE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: You probably are messing up with `PendingIntent`s, but for anyone to be able to answer the question you should provide the minimum relevant code.

Comment: Looking at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16435330/2841101.
It says you have to use the same builder next time. And using that builder you just update the tickertext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does not display the ticker text again if it is the same as before.

You may use **setTicker**  API of  `Notification.Builder` class instead of constructing ticker text using `Notification` object, as  `Notification.Builder` has been added to make it easier to construct Notifications.

And if your intentions is to re-display the same ticker text(from previously posted notification), then just add this Line :

```
mNotificationManager.notify(GATE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

After you posted your first notification.

So, your complete code looks like as below:

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_logo)
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentText(extras.getString("summary"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(extras.getString("extended_text"))
            )     //consider using setTicker here
            .setLights(Color.WHITE, NOTIF_LIGHT_INTERVAL, NOTIF_LIGHT_INTERVAL)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("mainActivityNotification", true);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 424242, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    final Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    //consider using setTicker of Notification.Builder
    notification.tickerText = extras.getString("title") + "\n" +
                              extras.getString("summary") + "\n" +
                              extras.getString("post_body");

    mNotificationManager.notify(GATE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    //second time onward, add your changed content like setContentText, setTicker etc.
    mNotificationManager.notify(GATE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```