# How to update notification title and text without sending new notification?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i have to update notification text and title without sending new notification. How do i do that i have tried below mentioned code.

code:-

```
notifica("Test", "Testinggggggggggg");
    m_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_another);

    m_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder.setContentTitle("Test3");
            builder.setContentText("Test3333333333");
            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

        }
    });
}

public void notifica(String title, String message) {
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setColor(color);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
    builder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885368/update-text-of-notification-not-entire-notification

Answer (score 6):

use this to update the title with same notification_id as you are using 0 for now

```
builder.setContentTitle(title);
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: you can use whatever builder instance you like. The only thing that matters is the notification ID

Comment: Then as per your answer i am doing correct

Comment: @Ragvender getting any issue ?

Comment: what is the issue you are getting by doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

From Android Developer

notify
added in API level 1

```
void notify (int id, Notification notification)
```

Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. **If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.**

Answer (score 0):

Using same notification id you can update notification text using local broadcast manager.