# notification.setPriority doesn't work

Tags: android, android-notifications

I set the notification priority to max, but it is still at the bottom of the notification area.

My code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setCustomContentView(views)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_24dp)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(notification);
notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

How it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the android documentation :

PRIORITY_MAX  was deprecated in API level 26.
Therefore Use IMPORTANCE_HIGH instead.

Comment: Nope, I have 23 API level on my device

Comment: check out this post:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758681/android-how-can-i-put-my-notification-on-top-of-notification-area

Comment: I already have code exactly how in this answer, but it doesn't work:(