# FCM Cannot show pop up when app in the background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

If fcm message contains "notification" section and app is in the background, Notifications delivered to the system tray and data in extras of the intent.

The problem is that I cannot change Importance for this notifications and they always do not show the popup.
I fixes this problem for api 26+, i added Notification channel with

```
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), name, importance);
```

and in the manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

But for the api 25- i cannot find the solutions. The one suggestions are to remove "notification" section and leave only "data", this will allow fcm deliver messages to

```
onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
```

when app is in background/foreground and I will be able to show my custom notifications.

Comment: Do you want to change an importance of the notification which is delivered when your app is in the background?

Comment: @wonsuc yes, because they are showing without pop-up.

Comment: How about the way sending with only `Data` payload? Is that way not applicable for you?

Comment: @wonsuc yes, i thought about this. But i cannot understand why fcm allows you in manifest change default notification icon/color/notification channel but doesn't allow to change importance.

Comment: If you really need to send with `Notification` payload, there is option name with `priority` which functionally same with `Importance`. But when the payload is `Notification` type, default `priority` option is "high". Try to put `priority` option as "high". Detail documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).

Comment: @wonsuc i tried. Priority and Importance are not the same.

Comment: Yeah. it's diffrent but functionally same. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#builder)

Comment: One more thing: Try to long press your notification and click the `MORE SETTINGS` and it will show the `Channels` which your created. Click the one of channel and now you can see the importance of the channel. Check if the importance is `high` or `urgent`.

Comment: I'm not sure if your issue is only for below of Android O.

Comment: @wonsuc importance is "Urgent" because i have created channel with `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH` and set this channle to `com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id`. But there is no ways to do the same for 25 and lower.

Comment: This is a quite strange behavior. On 25 and lower, it uses `Priority` instead of `Importance`. If you set `priority` option as "high" when you send FCM, it definitely shows like pop up. You can check related [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758681/android-how-can-i-put-my-notification-on-top-of-notification-area). Now what you can try is 1: Sending only with Firebase Console with Priority `High`. 2: Sending only Notification payload (without Data values). Try both and let me know the result.

Comment: Sometimes, it works correctly if you reboot the device or try diffrent device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution i have found is to use only `Data` payload and handle both background/foreground messages inside `onMessageReceived`method and show your custom notifications.

Comment: Hi, can you please put data payload json? what exactly you are sending? because I tried with data payload. but notification not received when app is in background.