# Xamarin forms ios app - fcm notification sound is not working

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can anyone help me with code required to enable fcm notification sound in xamarin forms ios app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved.
In notification payload from backend, sound parameter was not mentioned there.
Added sound="default" parameter in notification object, and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a sound file , the type should be `aiff, wav, caf` , and must be under 30 seconds when played.
2. Place it in in your app bundle or in the `Library/Sounds` folder of your app’s container directory.
3. Specify `sound` key in payload, the value is the file name.

Refer to

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

[How to config Firebase Push notification Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530830/how-to-config-firebase-push-notification-message)

Comment: thank you. Your 3rd step helped me.